# android opengl 2.0 stencil buffer not working

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, stencil-buffer

I'm facing very strange behaviour on my android device when I am trying to use stencil buffer feature. (GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);)

here is my code:

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
GLES20.glStencilFunc(GLES20.GL_GEQUAL, 1, 0xff);
GLES20.glStencilOp(GLES20.GL_KEEP, GLES20.GL_INCR, GLES20.GL_INCR);
GLES20.glStencilMask(0xff);

m_index_buffer.position(start_index);
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
                      n_indicies,
                      GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                      m_index_buffer);

GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

I got the following result:
[image: result of my code]

At first I was suspecting my code then I tried stencil example from:
[google stencil test](https://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/Android/Ch11_Stencil_Test/?r=47)
and got the following result:

[image: result of google's stencil test on my device]

It looks like there is some problem with opengl and stencil buffer feature...
I'm using Motorola Moto G with android 4.4.4.
Is this some kind of known bug? 
Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the stencil buffer wasn't cleared correctly. It is necessary to set stencil mask `glStencilMask(0xff)` before calling `glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)` to clear all bits of stencil buffer. Some devices might ignore stencil mask and always use 0xff when clearing stencil buffer. Even google's stencil test example has this bug :(

Comment: Thank you - that fixed the Chapter 11 Stencil Test for me.